# Import by scenario from code with excel data provider in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to import data in Acumatica under the section **Import by scenario (SM206036)**.

Here we have a scenario which is a simple scenario and it uses Excel data provider.

So when we log in to Acumatica and then go in that section, we click on **Upload File Version** button from the toolbar.

It opens a popup and ask to upload an Excel file.

Once uploading is done, we click on **Prepate & Import** button and it shows the data in the "Prepared Data" tab.

Now what I need is that I want to do the same process but programmatically.

So I am using Screen-based SOAP API for this.

I tried to import records one by one with no success.

I did not find any way to upload the Excel file using code.

Can anyone please suggest that what should I do to achieve this?

Please let me know if further details needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not adding as an answer because it is not SOAP API as you requested.  However, I need to provide my users a way to upload a standard file for processing.  I do this via PXImportAttribute on the child view in a Form/Grid screen.  The user selects which columns of the spreadsheet matches the columns of my child DAC (the grid) and import.  To enable uploading to a grid, you need to set the property AllowUpload = true on the grid definition.  (This is found under Mode in the Screen Editor for the grid layout properties.)